# Kubernetes load balancer without downtime

Tags: kubernetes

There is something that I'm missing about the load balancer service.
If I run a load balancer and my load gets spread over say 3 pods, do you have any guarantee that in case of multiple nodes, the same "type" of pods will be spread evenly over the nodes within the cluster?

If I understand it right, Kubernetes will try to spread different kind of pods over the nodes in order to achieve the most optimal use of resources.
But does this guarantee that pods exposing the same application will be spread evenly too?

The replication controller will take care that the a certain amount of pods is always running, but what happens in case of a node failure; let's say 1 node's network interface goes down, and 3 pods of the same type were scheduled on that node. In that case the rc will take care that they are up again on a different node, but how do you know that there won't be a temporary outage of that api? I imagine that when using a load balancer, this can be prevented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

Kube scheduler will try to spread your pods on best effort basis, but there are situations that will cause scheduling on the same node. So "no".

But you can use multiple features of kubernetes to achieve that, like pod anti affinity, daemon sets, host ports, descheduler etc. So "yes" if you know what you need exactly and how to achieve it.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I would assume that anyone who wants to load balance 2 pods would prioritise redundancy over minimal resource optimisation. In your experience, do you often experience node failure, and do you feel that Kubernetes at least tries to spread the same type of pods over different nodes? In terms of tradeoff, having an api be unavailable very rarely would be acceptable without the need to add additional complexity.

Comment: It is not common, at least in the most used platforms (AWS, IBM Cloud, Google Cloud or Azure) that the nodes fall. But if it occurs you have tools to prevent the pods from being deployed on that node (for example, cordon or drain)

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes tries to distribute the load of all his nodes. So it could be that you deploy all the pods in the same node.
As you say, in the event that the node fails, it would leave all your pods inaccessible.

As a developer, if you need to have pods distributed among different nodes, you have  tools for it:

- Daemon Set: Assures you that all (or some) nodes run a copy of the pod. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/
- Node Selector: You can define with labels those nodes where you want the pods to be deployed. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/admin_guide/scheduling/node_selector.html

There are other ways to achieve your objective like using affinity and anti-affinity or inter-pod affinity and anti-affinity. 
Here you have all the solutions that kubernetes offer in the documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/

Comment: I will check out affinity and anti-affinity later on. I am a bit turned off by this. Daemon set will create at least 1 pod on every node, which I also probably won't want. Node selectors on the other hand are not advised to be used in production. In the end I feel that load balancing over a desired number of nodes should be a built-in option.